# TC51 Zebra device barcode scanning problems in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, prism, barcode-scanner

I'm developing a mobile application with Xamarin Forms and Prism for MVVM structure.
I have a TC51 Zebra device and I need to intercept the barcode scan event.
The [SDK](http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-xamarin/latest/api/) is correctly installed in the project but the online example is for Xamarin.Android, not for Xamarin.Forms.
I don't know how to send the scanned barcode from Android project to portable project class.

Now I have this "Send call" in MainActivity.cs (Android project):

```
void scanner_Data(object sender, Scanner.DataEventArgs e)
    {
        ScanDataCollection scanDataCollection = e.P0;

        if ((scanDataCollection != null) && (scanDataCollection.Result == ScannerResults.Success))
        {
            IList <ScanDataCollection.ScanData> scanData = scanDataCollection.GetScanData();

            foreach (ScanDataCollection.ScanData data in scanData)
            {
                Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Send<Xamarin.Forms.Application, string>((Xamarin.Forms.Application)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "Barcode", data.Data);

            }
        }
    }
```

And this code in my ViewModel (Portable project) constructor:

```
Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Xamarin.Forms.Application, string>(Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "Barcode", (sender, arg) => { _pageDialogService.DisplayAlertAsync("Test Scan", "Data Received: " + arg, "OK"); });
```

When I try to read a barcode in this page the app crash.

I have also another problem: Now that I included the SDK in the project the app doesn't work in other devices, it crash on startup. I need to have a single application with barcode scanner support for TC51 Zebra devices and camera barcode scanning for other devices without integrated barcode scanner hardware. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you succeed creating the scanner application using xamarin forms? Could you please share the sample code. I am trying to achieve the same for few days but not sure how to link android to PCL or .Net standard

Comment: Yes, you can follow the instructions of Alessandro's answer. Please read also the comments.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample or the steps to achieve this. I tried with the comments and the code but seems to be not working. As @stezma said if you can provide one simple sample that could be really helpful to other people who try the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do something like this.

In your MainActivity.cs

```
    private App _my_application;
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        // .... various things....

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, savedInstanceState);
        _my_application = new App ();

        LoadApplication (my_application);

    }


void scanner_Data(object sender, Scanner.DataEventArgs e)
{
    ScanDataCollection scanDataCollection = e.P0;

    if ((scanDataCollection != null) && (scanDataCollection.Result == ScannerResults.Success))
    {
        IList <ScanDataCollection.ScanData> scanData = scanDataCollection.GetScanData();

        foreach (ScanDataCollection.ScanData data in scanData)
        {
            MessagingCenter.Send<App, string> (my_application, "ScanBarcode", data.Data);

        }
    }
}
```

then, in your "ContentPage"

```
    protected override void OnAppearing ()
    {
        base.OnAppearing ();

        // Enable receive barcode
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App, string> (this, "ScanBarcode", (sender, arg) => {

             // In "arg" there is your barcode
            try
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    DisplayAlert("BARCODE READ", arg, "OK");
                });

            }
            catch(Exception ex){

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        });

    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing ()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing ();

        // Disable receive barcode 
        MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<App, string> (this, "ScanBarcode");

    }
```

Comment: Hi Alessandro, thanks for your answer. I tried but I have the same problem, the application crash if I try to scan a barcode inside of the page. I can't debug because I don't have the usb cable. I tried with a try catch in the sender (MainActivity) and I've logged this message: "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.". I tried to log with a try-catch also in the page (Subscriber) but without success.

Comment: don't you have a stacktrace?

Comment: This is the StackTrace:   
at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00056] 
in <311df5b43f814151b0f66af52aca61d2>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <311df5b43f814151b0f66af52aca61d2>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter+Subscription.InvokeCallback (System.Object sender, System.Object args) [0x00076]

Comment: second part of stacktrace:  in <937957814f5d45be82b66795cb584841>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.InnerSend (System.String message, System.Type senderType, System.Type argType, System.Object sender, System.Object args) [0x0006b] in <937957814f5d45be82b66795cb584841>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Xamarin.Forms.IMessagingCenter.Send[TSender,TArgs] (TSender sender, System.String message, TArgs args) [0x00013] in <937957814f5d45be82b66795cb584841>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Send[TSender,TArgs] (TSender sender, System.String message, TArgs args) [0x00005]

Comment: third part: in <937957814f5d45be82b66795cb584841>:0 
  at MyPackage.MainActivity.scanner_Data (System.Object sender, Symbol.XamarinEMDK.Barcode.Scanner+DataEventArgs e) [0x00046] in <87a358a5e09c4a7ea016030fdd38cd6d>:0

Comment: seems a problem during the "send". I have a TC70... can you send me a prj so I can debug it?

Comment: I think your problem is not connected with EMDK but probably how you visualize your code... Try to use Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread, as in updated code

Comment: @ Alessandro Caliaro : If you have some working sample code? Could you please provide?

Comment: you have not a specific solution for Xamarin Forms.. you have to implement all in Xamarin Android project, then "send" data received from android prj to forms prj using, for example, MessagingCenter. You can find samples http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-xamarin/